# How to redirect to custom 404 page in razor pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, redirect, error-handling, .net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.0 and Razor Pages. I am trying to redirect to my custom 404 error page from Index.cshtml.cs manually (I have some imports and I want to show 404 when there are data issues).

**Startup.cs**:`enter code here`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }
   else
   {
       app.UseExceptionHandler("/errors/Error500");
       app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/errors/Error{0}");
       app.UseHsts();
   }
   ...
```

}

My 404 error page is located in /Errors/Status404.cshtml. When I run the application and try to go directly to /Errors/Status404 the page is resolving as expected.

Index.cshtml.cs with different ways how I was trying to make it work, unfortunately none of them works as I want them to - either it does not do anything or it returns system 404 page not my custom 404 page:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;

            HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Errors/Error404");

            return StatusCode(404); //tried to return IActionResult from OnGet()

            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
```

I also tried returning StatusCode(404) above and created a custom filter so I could redirect to my custom 404 from there, unfortunately this returns the server 404 error page too.

ErrorFilter:

```
public class ErrorFilter : Attribute, IAlwaysRunResultFilter
    {

        public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (context.Result is StatusCodeResult statusCodeResult &&
                statusCodeResult.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                //context.Result = new ObjectResult("Can't process this!")
                //{
                //    StatusCode = 404,
                //};
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("Errors/Error404");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I redirect to the custom error page in Index.cshtml.cs or from the ErrorFilter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [RedirectToPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel.redirecttopage?view=aspnetcore-3.0) helper method. Example

```
return RedirectToPage("Errors/Error404");
```

And you also need to change

```
public void OnGet()
```

To

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
```